# Get hardlink count for a file on Windows (without fsutil, which requires admin)

Tags: windows, ntfs, hardlink

I have various files which I've created as hardlinks to others using mklink. I need a command I can use inside a batch file to determine which files in a given directory have only one link to it. I know `fsutil hardlink list` can show me the links, but I need to be able to run the batch file as a regular user, whereas the above command won't run without admin rights. I'm looking for a way to do this without installing third-party applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way in batch off hand, but for PowerShell, the [Win32 API function GetFileInformationByHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the [BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which contains the `nNumberOfLinks` member, which is a numerical value indicating the number of hardlinks to the file.  (`1` means no hard links, so the number returned is the number of hard links + 1).

Comment: It might not matter a great deal but I assume that it's not actually the case that `nNumberOfLinks` is "the number of hard links + 1" but rather that the original filename counts as the first hard link.

Answer (score 3):

FindLinks from Sysinternals is an alternative to fsutil that will show you hard links. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/findlinks